# How to delete a file after XML Parsing has thrown an error in java?

Tags: java, xml, file

I have a piece of code that goes like this

```
File file = null;
try {

file = new file (filePath);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
// Do Stuff

} finally {

        if ( file.exists() ){
            file.delete();
        }
}
```

However if there is an error in the xml parsing, the file does not get deleted. Is there a way to fix this to ensure the file gets deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet this is under Windows.

Under Windows you cannot delete an open file, and db.parse() opens the file for reading.  Reconsider if you can pass in an InputStream which *you* are responsible for closing, and *then* you can delete the file.

Comment: It is under windows. And your suggestion worked. I am now giving the inputStream to db.parse(). Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I would put the delete in a try/catch block so you can handle exceptions

Comment: Remember to test the value returned by `delete()`